# controller methods matching ui-router states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my stateProvider, I am trying to following a more RESTful approach but given the controllers in Angularjs can contain all sorts of functions, I want to encapsulate the different routes to an appropriate part of the controller (**or if you have a better way, please advise**)

My current state:

```
.state('main.align.movements.new',{
        permissions: '<LOGGED_IN>',
        url: '/new',
        views: {
          '@main': {
            templateUrl: 'app/main/align/movements/new.html',
            // controller: function($scope){
            //   $scope.newMovement = new Movement()

            //   $scope.save = function(){
            //     $scope.newMovement.save()
            //   }

            //   $scope.cancel = function(){

            //   }
            // }
            controller: 'MovementsCtrl.hello'
          } 
        }
      });
```

As you can see, I commented out some of the code I was going to write as my controller was just about to get pretty large too quickly. Yet, I do depend on the `MovementsCtrl` for `/index` as it's large enough as it is. I was wondering if there is a way to have within the `MovementsCtrl` a way to encapsulate everything related to `/new` and `/edit`, etc. without having a huge Ctrl of code (for example, at `/new` I want to initiate an instance of `Movement` right away but don't want that initiation to persist even at `/edit` and I don't want to get ugly and do `$stateParams` to check the path given I am doing that for `$stateProvider` anyways )

Thoughts?

Comment: So you want to set controller's dynamically based on stateparams? You could create multiple controllers and set them for each states

Comment: I'd have 4-5 different controllers for each resource. Let alone injecting those into the module. That's not good no?